# Looping to Calculate a total of String array? Java

Tags: java, arrays

My coding is below beginner at this stage and I need help, My lecturer asked me to " use a  loop to calculate the total of all annual rents in the array" which means that the user enters what the rent would be over 12 months, How is it that I would make a loop to calculate the Sum of numbers that are not even entered in the code and are going through an array, I will put the code for the array in here and any help would be appreciated.

```
Scanner keyboardScanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
double[] array = new double[12]; 
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) { 
  System.out.println("Enter Rental for month[" + i + "]");
  array[i] = keyboardScanner.nextDouble();
}
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: your requirement is not clear.

Comment: How would you do it on paper?  (Hint: Do it on paper one row at a time, vs using the technique of adding all the numbers at once.)

Comment: I need to make a Loop, that would calculate the total of an array that does not have predefined definitions.

Comment: You have a loop.  Do something in it.

Comment: What do you see now in your output when you run your current code? What can you do with that? Even better: WHY are you seeing that output? If you understand what happens in your code, you understand what to do with that.

Comment: Like I Said im essentially useless in code, I am genuinely lost..

Comment: Don't Worry Take a deep breath, have some water and start reading Basic [Tutorials](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/)

Comment: @JakeGrim How about this: You can enter comment strings by using `//`. There, you can put in text that will be ignored when running. This can help developers giving text comments on places in the code. Try creating a whitespace in every single line you have, and write in comments what that line does exactly. ie: `Scanner keyboardScanner = new Scanner(System.in); //Loads a Scanner-object which can be used to read the input i need to sum.`

Comment: @TAsk If he wants to make a living out of this, he better starts appreciating coffee.

Comment: The code is made so that someone can input the "rent" and it will be output as 

Rental for month 1:
Rental for month 2: 
and such, i'm following the requirements set by my lecturer..

Comment: Ok, and now answer this question (by talking out loud, not in code-terms): What does your program currently do? Then answer your question: What needs to be changed or added so it will do as the requirement asks? Try to break down the question into smaller subquestions.

Comment: Im trying to understand what you mean by that and I thank you for truly trying to show me rather than just give me an answer.

Comment: @JakeGrim Read my updated answer and tell me what you think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look at your current code:

```
Scanner keyboardScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

This essentially loads in a Scanner-object, which in your case is being used to read input given from the user.

```
double[] array = new double[12];
```

You want to save numeric values for every month in a year. A year has 12 months, hence an array of doubles is created. This is a list of numerics (with size 12), so we can save the value for each month in here.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
```

So, before we can do anything, we need to know the input of the user. The user needs to insert a value 12 times. Hence, we ask the user 12 times to insert a value, then save that value in our created array.

The perfect way to achieve this is by using a for-loop. Essentially, what your loop does, is the following: first, we create a counter to tick through your loop, and we name it `i`. We set it to 0. Next, we tell the loop when to stop looping. In this case, it will stop if `i` is the same or higher then 12. Next, we tell the loop what to do after each loop. In this case, we increase the value with 1 by using `i++`.

```
  System.out.println("Enter Rental for month[" + i + "]");
  array[i] = keyboardScanner.nextDouble();
}
```

The value the user inserts, needs to be saved. So each time the user inserts a value, we can collect that value by using `keyboardScanner.nextDouble()`. The array you've created has 12 places: from array[0] to array[11]. Since we let `i` start on 0 and end on 11, we can set the value in the array on the i with the value inserted. So, the value you inserted the 3th time (`i`=2) gets saved on `array[2]`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

Now, we are going to do the same again. For the complete length of `array`, we are outputting the value in that array. This will result in: 
    System.out.println(array[0]);
    System.out.println(array[1]);
    System.out.println(array[2]);
    ...

Now, think of what you can do with that `array`. You're printing every number already in `System.out.println(array[i]);`. So, your value `array` contains all the numbers.

You should create a new `double` variable in which you can store the total value. And then, add all the values from the array to that `double`.

So, we are going to edit your original code:

```
Scanner keyboardScanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
double[] array = new double[12]; 
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) { 
  System.out.println("Enter Rental for month[" + i + "]");
  array[i] = keyboardScanner.nextDouble();
}

//Declaring the variable totalSum, which holds the total sum of all values in the array.
double totalSum = 0;

//So now, we need to do something with that array and sum up all the values in that array. 
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(array[i]);
}

//Outputting the result of the calculation
System.out.println("The total value is: " + totalSum);
```

Allright, let's put that in a textual way:

- I declare a variable named totalSum. I set that value to 0.
- For each value in the array, meaning for each month, I like to add up that amount to the totalscore totalSum.
- And now I will output that totalSum, so the user sees the sum of the months.

So, as a final touch, change it to the following:

```
//So now, we need to take each value and add them up to the totalSum
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(array[i]);
  totalSum = totalSum + array[i];
}
```

Comment: :/ It wasn't supposed to be answered FOR me, And even so when I enter that a new error pops up, Im missing a return statement somewhere.. My head is wrecked from this x)

Comment: @Joetjah I need to declare the totalSum In another case of a switch statement, is this possible with the coding provided? I tried this 
`code System.out.println("The annual rent for propery code "+propertyCode+" is:  " + totalSum);`

Comment: @JakeGrim It seems like your code, the one you've posted in the question, is situated in a method. In this case, your method does want something to return. Read this for more clarity: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_methods.html

Comment: @JakeGrim There is no switch-statement here. And I don't know where `propertyCode` comes from.

Comment: Thanks :) I fixed it! I had to move the property code and the totalSum constructors to the main method so that It could be accessed correctly

Comment: @JakeGrim You probably mean declarations, now constructors. Might sound naggy here, but there is a functional difference between them and understanding them will help in the future. But good thing it worked!